# Regex pattern with certain unicode categories

Tags: java, regex, unicode

I need a Regex pattern that **only** allows characters from the following (unicode) categories:

- Lowercase letter: https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/category/Ll
- Uppercase letter: https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/category/Lu
- Modifier letter: https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/category/Lm
- Titlecase letter: https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/category/Lt
- Other letter: https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/category/Lo
- Numbers: 0-9

The Regex `\w+` isn't suitable for these requirements.

`[0-9]+` will obviously fulfil the requirement *Numbers: 0-9*. How do I create a regex with all those unicode categories?

Comment: Use a character class. Something like `[\p{L}0-9]`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Is this `[\pLi\pLu\pLm\pLt\pL\0-9]` fine?

Comment: I am a bit confused by Regex101 which suggest following input `/\pX/g`. What is the `/` and `/g` for?

Comment: No, no need to escape `0` and there is no `\pLi`, there is `\p{Pl}`. I suggest using curly braces since it is more portable notation. Actually, these are all letters, so just use `\p{L}`

Comment: Forget about regex101, it does not support Java regex.

Comment: But does `\p{L}` not include unicode categories that are possible to use but aren't listed in my question?

Comment: There are [only 5](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/category). You listed them all.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate your help.